# Forbids comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c, struct, structure

```
struct student
{
    char am[7];/* èá íáé*/
    float final_grade;
    float exam_grade;
    float essay_grade;
};
struct student mathites[1];

do{
    printf("Dwse A.M.:");
    scanf("%s",&mathites[j].am);
} while((mathites[j].am<8120000) || (mathites[j].am>812015));
```

I saw post like this, but everyone asks about comparison with "==" so the answer is strcmp,
something similar for this case?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: it would be helpfull if you provided context about what you are trying to do and what you think you are doing.

Comment: i want A.M, to be acceptable as a number, between 8120000 and 812015

so, first i have to change char am[7]; to int am[7];

Comment: @Mikel - input as a number? Then you just need `int am;` and change the scanf format. If you want it as a string then to *change it* to a number that's the answer below.

Comment: Less than 8.12 million or greater than 812k. Isn't that all numbers?

Answer (score 1):

`something similar for this case?`

This one is a little different since you're trying to check if a string is within a range of a numeric value.

A few points first:

---

```
struct student mathites[1];
```

if you're going to declare an array of one you may as well not make it an array.

```
char am[7];/* èá íáé*/
```

If the largest value you want to compare against is 7 characters "8120000" then you want your array sized 8 (to include space for the null terminator)

```
scanf("%s",&mathites[j].am);}
```

You don't need to use the `&` operator when getting a string, and you should use a limiter so you don't overflow your string

---

So taken this into account I'd say the code should be more like:

```
struct student
{
      char am[8];/* èá íáé*/
      float final_grade;
      float exam_grade;
      float essay_grade;
};

struct student mathites;
do  {
    printf("Dwse A.M.:");
    scanf("%7s",mathites.am);}
```

Now your actual question, you need to convert the string to an number first, then check against the value:

```
    long str_value = strtol(mathites.am, NULL, 10);
}
while((str_value <8120000) || (str_value >812015));
```